# Power Automate - How to disable the "Final status: Approved" message

Tags: workflow, power-automate

I have a few **Approval** workflows and I was wondering if there is a way to stop/disable the second notification that it is sent after an Approved or Rejected action.

For example the screen shot below displays a number of **Final status: Approved** messages right after the user has **Approved** the pending action.

[image]

Is there a way/setting that disables the above messages?

Thank you in advance